# Al apretar el botón de "exportar" en Eclipse no sucede nada

Tags: java, eclipse, exportar

quiero exportar un pequeño programa que hice ejercitando.
Le doy click a **Archivo** se despliega el menú de opciones(abrir, guardar, exportar, etc...) y cuando le doy click a **Exportar** no pasa absolutamente nada.
Cualquier dato o sugerencia se agradece.

Answer (score 0):

Le das clic a exportar y no aparece ninguna ventana?

Primero prueba asegurarte de que tienes tu proyecto abierto.

Después prueba hacer **clic derecho en tu proyecto > exportar**.

Te debería aparecer el tipo de archivo que quieres, probablemente quieras **Java > Runnable JAR file**. Le das a siguiente, te aseguras de seleccionar tu clase Main del proyecto (la clase principal que tenga **public static void main()**), seleccionar el destino y ya esta, no hay nada más.

Suerte